# show/hide border around containing div? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a stamp form/preview for a site and am very new to javascript. I am battling to get the border px to show in the same colour as that in the colour selection box.

The javascript is:

```
function setColor()   {     
var color = document.getElementById("color").value;     
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color = color;   
} 
function border(border) {
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.border = border;
}
```

The CSS for the divs are as follows:

```
#myDiv  {
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:100px;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
border:1px solid #f1f1f1;
text-align:center;
}

#lineOne    {
position:relative;
padding:5px;
}

#lineTwo    {
position:relative;
padding:5px;
}

#lineThree  {
position:relative;
padding:5px;
}

#lineFour   {
position:relative;
padding:5px;
}
```

And the HTML like so:

```
Colour:
    <select id="color" onclick="setColor();">
        <option value="white">white</option>           
        <option value="black" selected="selected">black</option>           
        <option value="red">red</option>           
        <option value="lightblue">light blue</option>           
        <option value="darkblue">dark blue</option>           
        <option value="lightgreen">light green</option>           
        <option value="darkgreen">dark green</option>           
        <option value="yellow">yellow</option>           
        <option value="orange">orange</option>           
        <option value="pink">pink</option>           
        <option value="purple">purple</option>           
        <option value="gray">gray</option>         
    </select> 

    <select id="border"  onchange="border(this.value);">
        <option value="1px solid" selected="selected">1px</option>
        <option value="2px solid">2px</option>
        <option value="3px solid">3px</option>
        <option value="4px solid">4px</option>
        <option value="5px solid">5px</option>
    </select>


<div id="myDiv>
    <div id="lineOne">Some text here</div>
    <div id="lineTwo">Mores text here</div>
    <div id="lineThree">And even more</div>
    <div id="lineFour">And last text here</div>
```

Please can you tell me how to change the border px as well as change the border colour to that of the colour dropdown selection.

Comment: You're missing a `"` next to `myDiv` by the way.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `borderColor`

```
function setColor()   {     
  var color = document.getElementById("color").value;  
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderColor = color;   
}
```

Change `onclick` to `onChange` for the `color` `<select/>`

By modifying the `border` property you will effectively remove the associated color, change the value to `1px` - `5px` and use `borderWidth`

Instead of querying the dom each time, you can cache the element in a variable. `var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");`

Putting that all together you will end up with something like this:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

function setColor(elem) {
    myDiv.style.borderColor = elem.value;
}

function border(elem) {
    myDiv.style.borderWidth = elem.value;
}

<select id="color" onchange="setColor(this);">
     <option value="white">white</option>           
     <option value="black" selected="selected">black</option>           
     <option value="red">red</option>           
     <option value="lightblue">light blue</option>           
     <option value="darkblue">dark blue</option>           
     <option value="lightgreen">light green</option>           
     <option value="darkgreen">dark green</option>           
     <option value="yellow">yellow</option>           
     <option value="orange">orange</option>           
     <option value="pink">pink</option>           
     <option value="purple">purple</option>           
     <option value="gray">gray</option>         
</select> 
<select id="border"  onchange="border(this);">
     <option value="1px" selected="selected">1px</option>
     <option value="2px">2px</option>
     <option value="3px">3px</option>
     <option value="4px">4px</option>
     <option value="5px">5px</option>
</select>
<div id="myDiv">
    <div id="lineOne">Some text here</div>
    <div id="lineTwo">Mores text here</div>
    <div id="lineThree">And even more</div>
    <div id="lineFour">And last text here</div>
</div>
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/7vtfm/)**

If you want to be very pragmatic, you can even simplify it more by passing in the style property

```
function setStyle(elem, prop){
    myDiv.style[prop] = elem.value;
}
```

Comment: It also may be best to pass the element as a function argument (such as `this.selected.value`) for the inline function.

Comment: This is what i am trying to achieve, bieng the first time i am using javascript, i need help. I need the border colour to be the same as the colour of the dropdown box selection.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It works, except, i am trying to get the border colour the same as the text colour. But the user must be able to specify border width if required by the user.

Comment: If you want to do borderColor and color, simply assign both, `myDiv.style.color = color; myDiv.style.borderColor = color;`

Comment: Thank you Mark. And if i wanted to be able to toggle border on/off via a checkbox, how would this be done, considering the border must be the same colour as the text colour?

Answer (score 1):

Use `style.borderColor`:

```
function setColor()   {     
    var color = document.getElementById("color").value;     
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderColor = color;   
}
```